# UICollectionView is not loading cell second time

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am using `UICollectionview` to list some image as usual.

Code is simply getting data from api and update UICollectionView asynchronously. End of the API call code is updating data with `self.collectionView?.reloadData()`.

Also when user scrolls to bottom of `UICollectionView` api call is triggered again and update `photos` array and collectionview data. But at this second action is not adding new cells to `UICollectionView`

Here is code:

```
class PhotoStreamViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    var photos = [Photo]()
    var pageIndex = 1
    ...


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        allPhotos()
        ...

    }
    override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        pageIndex+=1
        allPhotos()
    }


    func allPhotos() {

        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": "Client-ID APIKEY"
        ]

        var json:JSON = JSON()

        Alamofire.request("https://www.apiurl.com/photos?page=\(pageIndex)&per_page=15&order_by=latest",method: .get, parameters: nil , encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON() { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
                //            debugPrint(response)
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    json = JSON(value)

                    for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
                        let image = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: subJson["urls"]["small"].stringValue)!))

                        if let photo = Photo(userName: subJson["user"]["name"].stringValue,comment: "dummy",image: image!,location: "Location",thumb: "thumb") {
                            self.photos.append(photo)
                        }
                    }

                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()


                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
        }
    }

}

extension PhotoStreamViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.photos.count
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AnnotatedPhotoCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! AnnotatedPhotoCell
        cell.photo = photos[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: You must create seperate API handler class for calling web services

Comment: I think you must check end of scroll for scrollview of collectionview. Also check if api is giving you required records for each page . Test your API once with Postman for different pages.

Comment: there are a few questions here: __(a)__ why does your method signature looks like `func allPhotos() {...}` rather than `func allPhotos(forPage pageIndex: Int)` {...}? __(b)__ why do you reload the data after fetching the photos rather than reload the new cells only? __(c)__ if you want to reload the data, why don't you reload it on the _main thread_?

Comment: **a)** yes it is not good practice but problem is not that. Thanks for advice
**b)** actually i am trying to add new cells i saw that method in a few tutorial on internet. But maybe you right i need to change this method
**c)** I couldn't grasp what do you mean _main thread_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after add this code under `self.photos.append(photo)`

```
  if(self.pageIndex > 1){
     let indexPath = IndexPath(item:self.photos.count-1, section: 0)
     self.collectionView?.insertItems(at: [indexPath])

  }
```

Also i had extension like :

`extension PhotoStreamViewController : PinterestLayoutDelegate`

after customize layoutattributes inside `PinterestLayout` it worked well

```
override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
```

Comment: Is there any perfect solution found?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload your collection view in main queue.Please try this.I think it's solve your problem

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I had tried this. Request already async so there is no problem there.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if let layout = self.IBcollection?.collectionViewLayout as? PInterestLayout 
{
      layout.cache = []
      layout.columnsYoffset = []
      layout.contentSize = CGSize.zero
}
self.IBcollection.reloadData()
```

Comment: checkout my solution.

Answer (score 0):

open `PinterestLayout`.

check `prepare` function. it containes below line. where `cache` is empty. whenever it reload it will get `cache` empty.

```
guard cache.isEmpty == true,let collectionView = collectionView else {return}
```

Replace above code with this:

```
guard let collectionView = collectionView else {return}
cache.removeAll() // Add this line while changing in array elements.
```